# 12.04 updates caused blue screen after login with taskbar or icons

Tags: 12.04, unity-2d

i'm still new to linux and have been testing it out on my laptop.

i ran updates on ubuntu 12.04lts and something failed along the way. after reboot, when i log in, the screen is blue and the icons and taskbar are not displayed. i cannot even open up the terminal.

i ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and that fixed the issue, however, i am only limited to ubuntu at login. the ubuntu-2d option (unity-2d) is now missing. i tried reinstalling unity-2d with `sudo apt-get install unity-2d` and to no luck.

sorry i'm a newb. any advice is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you could do is to check if the package you are looking for is in the repositories. I have checked the packages list for Ubuntu and for Precise (12.04) it is listed.
You can do this 2 ways. The first would be using something like Synaptic. This is a graphical apt-get manager which can be found in the Software Center and then search for unity-2d. Alternatively, you could also look using the terminal with the command:

```
    sudo apt-cache search unity-2d*
```

That should list all packages that have unity-2D.

I would also make sure that you haven't actually done a distribution upgrade, in which case you would now have 12.10 which does not include Unity-2D.

Let me know if you can find the packages

Comment: you were correct. somehow it upgraded to 12.10

Comment: I thought as much, I wish I could tell you how to downgrade but this really isn't a safe option. The best that you could do is backup all your personal files and do a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04. Then what you want to do whilst doing a fresh install is to make your /home a seperate partition, so should in the future things go wrong, you can do a clean install while keeping files in tact. Also make sure that when you have 12.04 and updates are available, to check which packages are being upgraded, and also don't run dist-upgrade